# Did Hugo Cabret and other characters really exist?

Tags: character, historical-accuracy, hugo

In [Hugo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_%28film%29), forgotten [Georges Méliès's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_M%C3%A9li%C3%A8s) life, success and master piece films are revealed to us, but the movie was not just about him.

It was about the boy Hugo and all his courageous deeds. My question is did he really exist or it was just fantasy? As well as all the other characters shown in the film.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The characters information I am able gather are:

- The character of Hugo is entirely fictional.
- Georges Méliès's had two wives, first wife Eugénie, who was married to Méliès during the time he made films (and who died in 1913). And second Jeanne d'Alcy, they did not marry until 1925. In film Eugénie got skipped and Jeanne presented as fusion of both of his wives.
- Madeleine Malthête-Méliès is the name of granddaughter which Méliès lives with.
- His two brothers, that helped him during film making, were missing in story.
- In the movie, Hugo's father dies in a museum fire along with the automaton. Well, in real life, Robert-Houdin's Hand Writing and Drawing Automaton was in Barnum's American Museum in NYC. That museum burnt to the ground and along with it, the Hand-Writing Automaton that was created by Robert-Houdin.
- The train crash dream is inspired from [Montparnasse derailment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montparnasse_derailment), real life event, not related to Méliès.
- René Tabard is also a fictional character.

*Can't gather more information now, will try to incorporate them, if got any sooner or later.*

(Source :[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_%28film%29), [2](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Hugo), [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_M%C3%A9li%C3%A8s), [4](http://www.themagicdetective.com/2011/11/hugo-and-real-george-melies.html), [5](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2011/11/30/martin_scorsese_s_hugo_the_real_movies_that_inspired_scorsese_s_film.html))